# json mapper writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter for multiple json objects separated by new line

Tags: java, json, jackson

I had multi line json Strings separated by new line character. I am using jackson version 1.9.13 For example

```
{"name":"firstPerson","age":25,"gender":"male"}\n
{"name":"secondPerson","age":30,"gender":"male"}\n
{"name":"thirdPerson","age":25,"gender":"male"}\n
...............
```

The delimiter may be \n\r or \n based on the operating system using. Basically it is a batch record processing where we save all the contents back to database . But we also save the entire request as well .

My requirement is to get the multiple lines of json object when i use in prettyprint format.Please find the code

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, JsonParseException, IOException {
        //mapper.configure(Feature.ALLOW_BACKSLASH_ESCAPING_ANY_CHARACTER, true);
        //mapper.configure(Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_CONTROL_CHARS, true);
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
        String json = "{\"name\":\"firstPerson\",\"age\":25,\"gender\":\"male\"}\n{\"name\":\"secondPerson\",\"age\":30,\"gender\":\"male\"}\n{\"name\":\"thirdPerson\",\"age\":25,\"gender\":\"male\"}";
        System.out.println(objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(objectMapper.readValue(json, Object.class)));
        System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```

The out put is :

```
{
 "name" : "firstPerson",
 "age" : 25,
"gender" : "male"
}
```

But i want to display as :

```
{
    "name" : "secondPerson",
    "age" : 30,
    "gender" : "male"
  }
{
  "name" : "thirdPerson",
  "age" : 25,
  "gender" : "male"
}
{
  "name" : "firstPerson",
  "age" : 25,
  "gender" : "male"
}
```

I know its not a standard way of json string. json string always enclosed in flower brasis . But as it is already existing system i dont want to break the system to change the code . It can be done simply using any of the string handling functions in java but i need to use jackson and jackson's pretty printer.
Is there a way to get this done ?

Thanks,
Eresh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String person= "{\"name\":\"firstPerson\",\"age\":25,\"gender\":\"male\"}\n{\"name\":\"secondPerson\",\"age\":30,\"gender\":\"male\"}\n{\"name\":\"thirdPerson\",\"age\":25,\"gender\":\"male\"}";

Object json = mapper.readValue(person, Object.class);
            System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(json));
```

Answer (score 3):

Your json string is made of 3 JSON objects, so you need to format them one at the time and then concatenate them:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
String json = "{\"name\":\"firstPerson\",\"age\":25,\"gender\":\"male\"}\n{\"name\":\"secondPerson\",\"age\":30,\"gender\":\"male\"}\n{\"name\":\"thirdPerson\",\"age\":25,\"gender\":\"male\"}";
String[] jsons = json.split("\n");
String output = "";

for (String str : jsons) {
    output += objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(objectMapper.readValue(str, Object.class)) + "\n";
}

System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: Thats right I already did that . But my question is there a possiblity that json think that my json string which contains array of objects some thing like that . For  example objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(objectMapper.readValue(str, Object[].class)) . so that json mapper will automatically realize that hey i have object of strings rather than a single line string . Though my json string has some deveations

Comment: Note that if you write many files you probably should build the default pretty printer once before the loop and reuse it in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just like: 
On demand

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Object obj = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(objectMapper.readValue(stringValue, Object.class));
```

For older version replace `writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()` with `defaultPrettyPrinterWriter()`

Globally

```
objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
Object obj = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(objectMapper.readValue(stringValue, Object.class));
```